# Why do I have to install apache2-utils when installing node.js?

Tags: apt, apache2

I'm about to install node.js ([Question about installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-node-js)). It says that I have to install some packages first for using git and stuff if I'm running a clean server, which I actaully do:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils git-core
```

Okay - everything's good so far. But why should I install some apache stuff, when I only want to use node.js?

Do I really need that?

---

This question is only relevant for people, who want to [compile node themselves](https://askubuntu.com/a/49391/31398). I recommend using the simpler and safer  [`apt-get` method](https://askubuntu.com/a/83290/31398).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name `apache2-utils` is misleading. It is not a part of the Apache server. Apache just depends on [stuff that you can find](http://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/apache2-utils) in this package. As it turns out, the compiler (or node itself) depends on the same utilities.

This means, that after the compilation and installation of node `apache2-utils` can be safely removed via `sudo apt-get remove apache-2utils`. This applies to the other packages aswell. However I don't recommend removing any of the packages. You will likely want to recompile node as soon as there's a new version.

**tl;dr** You're doing nothing wrong, when installing `apache2-utils`. It is a package of utilities, needed for compiling node. You can remove it after compilation.

Comment: I add the [link for the Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/apache2-utils) for convenience, but I think your Squeeze version fits better in this case.