# How to install node.js 0.4.7?

Tags: 11.04

I am going to develop a node.js application which will run on heroku.

This means I will need to install node.js version 0.4.7 on my ubuntu 11.04 -- though the version from the distribution repository is 0.2.6.

What is the recommended way to install it?

(I was able to download the tarball containing the source from nodejs's web site and compile it, but I'd rather not do 
    sudo make install
because I'd like to be able to install it in my home directory (or, if needed to have it system-wide, have a clean way to do an uninstall).

Note: I've seen [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-node-js) but I don't want either to sudo make install nor install the latest release from the ppa.

Comment: Adding as a comment since I don't have enough reputation for self-answering.


I found out that for nodejs there is nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm which works in a very similar way to rvm for ruby.

So, once nvm is installed, it is just matter to do `nvm install v0.4.7` and you're done, exactly like you did with rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that for nodejs there is nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm -- it works in a very similar way to rvm for ruby.

So, once nvm is installed, it is just matter to do a `nvm install v0.4.7` followed by a `nvm use v0.4.7` and you're done!
(by the way, this works for installing any version of node.js you need -- and you can also have multiple versions installed aside)