# How do I make my terminal display graphical pictures?

Tags: command-line, image-viewers

This is a quick mockup I copy and pasted together. I imagine this being super cool and useful.

Does something like this exist already?

[image: http://imgur.com/Z3DbS]

Comment: I always just use `feh`! I know it's not in the terminal, but it does it's job.

Comment: Terminal is not for graphics, it can only display unicode characters, and do some coloring. The best you can get is ASCII art.

Comment: I love to use the terminal for graphics with [itermplot](https://github.com/daleroberts/itermplot#itermplot), which is unfortunately macOS only.

Comment: Is this question motivated by the little beer image in Homebrew? That's an emoji.

Comment: If you are on an Ubuntu server trying to view them on a Mac, this works beautifully: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457076/7000

Comment: @Dennkster if you find the appropriate tool, mention it.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

*Update 2021-03-02*

### Viu

[Viu](https://github.com/atanunq/viu) is an image viewer that can display images using either the kitty, iterm, or libsixel approach. It also has a fallback mode to display blocky ascii images.

---

*Update 2018-12-31*

### kitty icat

The all around terrific terminal emulator kitty has an [`icat` command to display images](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/kittens/icat.html) (does not work within tmux). Kitty also enables [image previews within ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/pull/1077) (a terminal file manager), which is the method I currently use the most often (works within tmux).

---

### 1. w3m

While the main purpose of `w3m` is to provide in-console web browsing, it can also be used to view images in terminal. The relevant packages to install are `w3m` and `w3m-img` (on Ubuntu at least). You then need to disable the external image viewer wither by passing `-o ext_image_viewer=0` or by going into the options menu ('o') inside `w3m` and disable external image viewing.

Now, typing `w3m <image_name>` will display the image in terminal. `w3m` will use the entire terminal window, so you cannot see your previous commands until quitting `w3m` (think `less`, not `cat`). Note that if the image is to big to fit the terminal window, it will still be opened externally (in imagemagick for me). Also note that even though I read multiple places that `w3m` inline images would not work for `gnome-terminal`, it is working fine for me. It is a little annoying that you have to type `q` twice to close first the image and then `w3m`.

### 2. Terminology

`tycat` is part of `terminology` and displays images like `cat` displays text files and like [`imgcat`](http://www.iterm2.com/images.html) works for iTerm2 on OS X.

### 3. libsixel + mlterm/xterm

Install `libsixel-bin` and any compatible terminal (examples mentioned under ['Requirements' of this readme](https://github.com/saitoha/PySixel#Requirements), for example `mlterm` or `xterm` compiled with the right flags and you can view images with the `img2sixel` command. Both these packages are available in the Ubuntu repos.

### 4. FIM

Then there is [FIM](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/) which is an improved version of `fbi`. The homepage states that it can display images not only with the framebuffer, but also with X. However, it won't install for me. **Edit** I got it running by downloading the 0.5 trunk version, running `./configure --disable-exif` and then temporarily removing `anaconda` (python distribution) from my path since it caused a conflict with `libpng` before running `make` and `sudo checkinstall` (you need to write in a version number manually with `checkinstall`, but it makes it easier to remove than `make install`). However, images are still displayed in a separate window, although like with `fbi` you do not need to be running X which is kind of cool.

### 5. jupyter-qtconsole

You could also get creative and use the jupyter-qtconsole as your system console, configure it to show plots inline (`%matplotlib inline`) and then [display the image using matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) =)

### 6. feh

`feh` is using X to display images, but `feh -x` pops them up in a borderless window that can be quickly closed with `q` or `x`. Although images are not displayed in the terminal per say, I thought it was worth mentioning since it is the least intrusive way I have found so far and what I am using until `gnome-terminal` gets an `imgcat`/`tycat` equivalent.

Comment: w3m is using caca-utils so it would be better to just use it directly (cacaview e.jpg)

Comment: `apt install libsixel-bin mlterm;
mlterm;
img2sixel test.jpg` works on Ubuntu 19.10! I tried xterm too, but no output there

Comment: @user1133275 actually they both use `imlib2` so it doesn't seem to matter much ;)

Answer (score 86):

Maybe [caca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) is what you want. For **images**:

```
sudo apt-get install caca-utils
cacaview /PATH/TO/image.jpg
```

Make sure your terminal window is big enough.

For example, here is how [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAZtS.png) is displayed in `cacaview`:

[image: Screenshot]

I sometimes used it for fun to **watch videos as ASCII** in mplayer :) Like this:

```
mplayer -vo caca /PATH/TO/video.mpg
```

Comment: Very helpful - a command from caca-utils that should display images inline in the terminal is `img2txt`

Comment: There's a new player on the field now: https://github.com/ichinaski/pxl --- In a quick test the pictures look better than in cacaview. (I wanted to add a new answer, but the site didn't let me (?))

Comment: "*watch videos as ASCII*" But... why?

Comment: this opens another window. OP asked for terminal. You should suggest img2txt instead, I think.

Comment: That depends on your environment. In a non-X terminal it opens as expected. In X there's probably a solution too. I figure it may depend on the terminal used or its dimensions.

Comment: `"watch videos as ASCII" But... why? ` because you want to? because you need to peek the video and the only thing you got is terminal? Because if you do not need something it does NOT mean others follow.

Comment: What is the commandline example for mpv for an image such as foobar.png ?

Comment: `mpv --quiet --vo tct VIDEO.mp4` @shevy; @Derek朕會功夫 Just because. I do have a system though that I run without X11. In this case it's better than playback without video at all. @dsstorefile1: Great hint!

Comment: This looks like porn from the 90s.

Comment: I still like the ascii aesthetic therefore, `mpv --quiet --vo caca VIDEO.mp4`

Comment: I get "sudo: apt-get: command not found"?

Comment: `apt-get` or now also just `apt` is for Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu. You are probably not on such a distribution. What is your Linux?

Comment: I'm not installing something named "caca".

Answer (score 62):

I have written a small C++ tool to convert images to ANSI RGB control codes and Unicode block graphics characters for modern terminals supporting these features: https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer.git
cd TerminalImageViewer/src/main/cpp
make
sudo make install
```

Usage:

```
tiv <image(s)>
```

**Edit**: Changed links / instructions to the main repository; added usage.

Examples:

[image: TerminalImageViewer]

Comment: This looks very nice! But is it Java or C++?

Comment: It used to be Java but the need for a JVM for this simple task irked me, so I have ported it to C++ (the screen shots still show the java command though)

Comment: Way better than cacaview!

Comment: This is an amazing tool. Definitely slower, but much better than caca. Is there any quality loss when using the "256 bit mode"? (since I have to, normal mode is messed up)

Comment: 256 color mode uses only 256 fixed colors (8 bit) -- it's quite a bit worse than 24 bit RGB mode.

Comment: Very good results ! Thanks ! Very useful with ssh when no x server is awailable !

Comment: It failed to work for me. More details here: https://gist.github.com/nahiyan/09f7b4a2f111d75e100c636e2b6a2af6

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me over SSH (Ubuntu 18.04 on both machines).

Answer (score 50):

I made a very quick, simple one line shell function which solves the original question exactly as requested in the mockups. Note the screenshots below are actual images, not mockups.

```
function lsix() { montage -tile 7x1 -label %f -background black -fill white "$@" gif:- | convert - -colors 16 sixel:-; }
```

[image: Screenshot of using the lsix command]

Prerequisites are minimal: xterm and ImageMagick (`apt-get install xterm imagemagick`). Your xterm must be in vt340 mode, which you can either set in `~/.Xresources` or from the command line (`xterm -ti vt340`).

Limitations: Only 16 colors are used over *all* images shown. That means, an image might look better when viewed on its own. (See below).

[image: Screenshot showing 16 color limitation]

**UPDATE**

While my above answer is still correct, I've created an even better shell script which is able to do an 'ls' of images directly into a terminal. There are all sorts of improvements I added to make the images look better (more colors, proper alpha, JPEG orientation, handling lots of images, compact tile layout,...). It's still a fairly small program, but I figured people might want to customize it, so I've put it up on github: https://github.com/hackerb9/lsix.

Answer (score 33):

You can't do so in a terminal window, but you can do so in a [Linux console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console) using `fbi`. You need a framebuffer to allow this to work:

```
sudo apt-get install fbi
```

Go to a Linux console (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and enter `fbi <filename>`

It should show your image.

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal" vs "tty"? Aren't they the same thing? https://askubuntu.com/questions/506510/what-is-the-difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line

Comment: Didn't work for me. But "caca" tool worked.

using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)

Comment: @Wernight Ctrl + Alt + F1/F2/F3 gives you a tty under ubuntu (Ctrl + Alt + F8 to get back).

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli I get the same error as you when using an X-based terminal instead of a tty.

Comment: There is also [FIM](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/) which is an improved version of `fbi`. The homepage states that it can display images not only with the framebuffer, but also with X. However, it won't install for me.

Comment: @cheflo What I mean it that it also works in a terminal, not just a tty.

Comment: Good news iTerm2 v3 can show images inline check https://www.iterm2.com/images.html

Comment: @cheflo on ubuntu 16.04 LTS returning is (Ctrl + Alt + F7)

Comment: I wonder how safe it is to let fbi handle your images :/

Comment: You definitely **can** display images in a terminal window. see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SasrQ7pnbA 
Sixel is supported by *xterm*.

Answer (score 31):

Another tool is [catimg](https://github.com/posva/catimg) which can be installed using

```
sudo apt-get install catimg
```

It does not actually view the image but turn it into colored characters.

[image]

Answer (score 25):

Another alternative is terminology:

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ibPziLRGvkg

You can install it on Ubuntu by adding the [enlightenment-git](https://launchpad.net/~enlightenment-git/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:enlightenment-git/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terminology
```

Or in recent Ubuntu releases >= Vivid (15.04) it can be fetched from the official repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install terminology
```

To view an image, type `tycat IMAGENAME`, and to view a list of images, type `tyls -m`.

Comment: `tycat` to display an image inline and `tyls -m` to display medium sized thumbnails in a directory.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hannes-janetzek/enlightenment-svn
*doesnt Work*

Comment: I've updated the answer to point out to the more recent enlightenment ppa

Comment: @chilicuil `terminology` is [in the official Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/terminology), no PPA needed.

Comment: @cat the original answer was written before vivid was released and at that time terminology wasn't available, the enlightenment ppa still have precise/trusty packages and more up to date terminology versions. However maybe editing the answer to point out than frozen terminology versions are available in recent ubuntu releases will be helpful.

Comment: I got ERR<3345>: emotion-generic ....... _players_load() no generic players available;  when trying to `tycat <image.png>`

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to get this functionality via SSH is there?

Answer (score 14):

Just to add to the collection (perhaps also for future me), there is also an actively developing/maintained software named [chafa](https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa) that works similar to [catimg](https://github.com/posva/catimg). Both can show images in addition to GIFs.

## chafa:

```sh
# install chafa
sudo apt install chafa
# open a file
chafa file.gif
```

[image: showcasing chafa]

## catimg:

```sh
# install catimg
sudo apt install catimg
# open a file
catimg filename.gif
```

[image: Showcasing catimg]

Comment: Yes, chafa looks great!

Comment: Chafa works great for me in the default Ubuntu Gnome terminal on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 12):

There's actually such a project named [TermKit](https://github.com/unconed/TermKit/), if you'd like to test it - check out http://blog.easytech.com.ar/2011/05/21/playing-with-termkit-with-chrome/ but it's quite unfinished (since you seem to have a Mac, you should try the Mac-version since it's "the original")

So yes, it's an idea worth exploring, however - the switch between graphical and text-only mode must be quick since I don't always need the images viewed. Also - it needs to be fully compatible with e.g. Vim..

Comment: I read about this project once before on [Slashdot](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/05/19/1648200/imagining-the-cli-for-the-modern-machine). Sounds intriguing! Too bad you need Google Chrome to use it...well, okay, it's not too bad if you use Chrome to begin with, but it seems like an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Yeah, I it could work if you hack a bit with Qt's WebKit - but fortunately we have the `chromium-browser` in the repos, so that it's quite easy to install something Chromelike - I haven't really tried TermKit on my computer (w/ Chromium installed, but using Fx as main) since I'm quite dependent on Vim, and can't really use a terminal that won't give me my beloved text editor ;)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [Joel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/698064/365173), [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/) terminal file manager with `w3mimgdisplay` extension can show images in full color and also supports "oldschool ASCII art previews". [Here](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Image-Previews) is how you can enable it. This may not be the exact thing you were looking for but a way to preview images in terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a tool to do this. I named mine Show Image In Terminal (`siit`).  It assumes you have a 256 color terminal and UTF8 support, and it's written in Perl.

I dropped it in my `~/bin`.  It assumes you have Image::Magick, Term::Size, Getopt::Long and Time:HiRes, which should all be available in your distro's repositories, or CPAN.

My intent was to ssh into my house, and quickly view images without launching a display over X. Script scales to appropriate width/height for the terminal you are in. I used UTF8 characters to effectively double the vertical resolution of your terminal, which really helps clarity. YMMV.

[Sample shots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SNzZ.jpg)

[Source code here](http://antipathy.nonserviam.net/utilities/siit)

Comment: It's "siit", not "shit" (seriously....)

Comment: It was originally called termpeg, but that's too hard to remember and didn't tab-complete well.  Besides, "this code is a piece of siit" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: The source code link doesn't work for me, but I found a version on the internet, here is a mirror: https://gist.github.com/certik/4336299de10f400ee49943bd9f8a8ba6

Comment: Any chance you can provide a bundled version? I always give up when I have to install libraries.

Answer (score 6):

This does not exist; `gnome-terminal` is only capable of diplaying text, at least as far as I know.

However, you *can* call an image viewer from the commandline to see your pictures in a particular folder. So, going off of your mockup above showing you listing all .jpg pictures in the current folder, you can use Eye of GNOME (Ubuntu's default image viewer) from the commandline for something similar:

```
eog *.jpg &
```

Note that the window which comes up will only show one image at a time, though you can use the provided arrow buttons to cycle between them.

Comment: if running from a terminal, `eog *.jpg & disown` is better as otherwise the EOG will likely exit when the terminal closes. *N.B. I wish EOG was still Ubuntu's defualt image viewer - shotwell is good, but tries to index my 30GB+ of pictures.... and is slow and annoying anyway*

Comment: All previous answers prove this post wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some solutions in `node.js` (Installation instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js)).

1. **[picture-tube](https://github.com/substack/picture-tube)**
   [image]
2. **[imaging](https://github.com/switer/imaging)**
   [image]

To install either, type `npm install -g <package_name>` where `package_name` is either of `picture-tube` or `imaging`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [ueberzug](https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug), which you can install using pip. Here I'm using it with [fzf-ueberzogen](https://github.com/seebye/fzf-ueberzogen), so to display image previews, you simply run the `fzf-ueberzogen.sh` command in the current directory as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can indeed display images in the terminal. What we need is a terminal program that supports the Sixel protocol or a similar protocol. 
lsix, written by hackerb9, is one such program that uses Sixel to display images. 
There are also other programs like [timg](https://github.com/hzeller/timg) that utilize Sixel. And timg can be easily installed via package management software on most Linux distributions and macOS(via Homebrew). 
You can find more programs that use Sixel at this URL: https://www.arewesixelyet.com/.