# How to open Google captcha image in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: 14.04, xterm

I am using Lynx on Ubuntu to open Google.com for search but it is showing image captcha (may be because of shared IP). Lynx don't show images and I tried to use w3m but that is also not showing images.

When I run "Env" at command line, it shows

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

I thought xterm shows images by default with w3m. What else I can do to see images in terminal and specially Google captcha ?

Edit -

When trying to use "links2 -g", I am getting this error -

```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.2.10 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2001-2008  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2014-10-24 12:33)  (*) Direct/Memcpy: Using libc memcpy() (!) Direct/Util: opening '/dev/fb0' and '/dev/fb/0' failed
    --> No such file or directory (!) DirectFB/FBDev: Error opening framebuffer device! (!) DirectFB/FBDev: Use 'fbdev' option or set FRAMEBUFFER environment variable. (!) DirectFB/Core: Could not initialize 'system_core' core!
    --> Initialization error! Could not initialize any graphics driver. Tried the following drivers: x: Can't open display ":0.0" fb: Could not get VT mode. directfb: Initialization error!
```

Comment: if you are using xterm. give a try to link2 browser. links2 -g  will enable graphic option... depends on xserver. so you can see static images there

Comment: Here's some CLI image viewers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures