# What configuration is required to render images in terminal?

Tags: command-line, tty

I'm looking for a way to open an image in tty*

I have this Memory about hearing w3m can render images.

If I use w3m to open an image in a GUI it spawns a child window.
This was the only way with my current settings to get it to show an image.

Is there a supported file list for w3m? I might have been trying to open an unsupported file type.

Is there some configuration in Ubuntu where I can permit or add the ability to draw images in terminal?

Is there a different command that can render an image in terminal?

I know this question has been asked a few times before but at least one had no solution and it was closed for being unclear; there were answers on other questions but they suggested using commands to spawn x-windows or they would use colored spaces to render the image.

The solution I'm looking for is something that can get pixel level access on a character block or that this is not possible [in Ubuntu 17.10 but it is possible in ...].

If the only available answer is to convert the image to colored ANSII/Unicode I would be super interested but it isn't the answer to this question.

Comment: Why do you want graphics in a non-graphic display?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures already asked and answered.