# see images preview in terminal

Tags: kde, konsole, previews, image-viewers

I search for a program to list pictures graphically in my terminal.

I found this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures) but most of answers provide a solution to view the images in terminal which is not my case because I want to list pictures and not seeing them.

I search for a program such as [lsix](https://github.com/hackerb9/lsix.git) to list images in my terminal.

My Terminal is `konsole` and doesn't support Sixel and that's why I can't use `lsix` program.

Can you give me an alternative program?

**UPDATE** My system Information as requested by [@K7AAY](https://askubuntu.com/users/197910/k7aay):

```
$ uname -r
5.4.150-1-MANJARO
```

I have [Manjaro KDE](https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/kde/) but, for this concept, you can consider it as Kubuntu.
Still more info? look at below output:

```
$ screenfetch

 ██████████████████  ████████     OS: Manjaro 21.1.5 Pahvo
 ██████████████████  ████████     Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.150-1-MANJARO
 ██████████████████  ████████     Uptime: 2h 44m
 ████████           ████████     Packages: 2163
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Shell: zsh 5.8
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Resolution: 1366x768
 ████████  ████████  ████████     DE: KDE 5.86.0 / Plasma 5.22.5
 ████████  ████████  ████████     WM: KWin
 ████████  ████████  ████████     WM Theme: Kvantum
 ████████  ████████  ████████     GTK Theme:  [GTK2/3]
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Icon Theme: breath
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Disk: 53G / 73G (76%)
 ████████  ████████  ████████     CPU: Intel Core i5-5200U @ 4x 2.7GHz [53.0°C]
                                  GPU: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
                                  RAM: 4158MiB / 7879MiB
```

Comment: An alternative program that works in `konsole` or alternative terminals more suitable for displaying images such as `xterm`, `urxvt`, `kitty`, or `alacritty`? The terminal file manager does display images in `konsole` but the display is buggy, the new image doesn't completely replace the previous one.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here