# Installing the latest Node.js / MongoDB?

Tags: software-installation, install-from-source, nodejs, mongodb

How can I install Node.js and MongoDB so they are the most current versions?  The available versions from package manager are not up to date, and [PPA from Chris Lea](https://askubuntu.com/a/83290/88546) for Node.js doesn't get updated on a regular basis.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The packages in the Advanced Packaging Tool (AptGet) do not work always or are outdated at times on Ubuntu.  I suggest building [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org) from source and installing the recommended **.deb** package for Ubuntu provided by [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org).

---

Video Demo:

http://youtu.be/SWztoBP7RQQ

---

### Requirements

These are needed for building and running.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential lamp-server^
```

---

### **Build & Install Node.js**

Node.js can easily be installed from its source package located on the front page of nodejs.org.  It allows you to build the most compatible package for install.

*Note: I recommend not installing the Linux Binaries for your system architecture (ie. x32, x64) as they are missing components you may require such as NPM.*

[image: Node.js Front Page]

You can right click on the **INSTALL** button to copy the source package link and do the following also in your terminal console.*(Example shows how to install current version as of 07-31-2014)*

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.30/node-v0.10.30.tar.gz
```

Decompress and enter the directory.

```
tar -xvzf node-v0.10.30.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.30
```

Configure the make file for your machine then build and install as a root user.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Test to make sure it was installed.

```
node -v
```

You have also installed the [Node Package Manager](http://www.npmjs.org).  Type the following to see items that were installed with version numbers:

```
npm version
```

---

### Install Recommended MongoDB Package

MongoDB documentation suggest installing the .deb package provided by them for the latest versions as long as you are using running and Ubuntu over 9.10 "Karmic". Doc: [Installing on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Acquire key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Acquire source list:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Update package manager and install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Test if MongoDB shell runs:

```
mongo
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit.

*Note: mongo-10gen can be updated and upgraded from AptGet. You do not need to perform the install action again unless you remove it.*

Comment: I also want to add the reference to '[How do I install the latest version of node.js?](http://askubuntu.com/a/83290/88546)' suggest that the official PPA is the one from [Chris Lea](https://chrislea.com).  This is **incorrect** but it has been the most reliable one as of yet.  This is why updates fall behind because people must wait for him to have time to get to updating it.

Comment: You can download the latest node binaries using: wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/$(curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | egrep -io "\"node-v.*-linux-x64.tar.gz\"" | sed "s/\"//g”)

Comment: @EngineerDollery  Are those always stable?

Comment: I don't know if it's guaranteed or not -- you'd have to ask the node guys, but I can't find any evidence that they're not stable. There is a nightlies dist too.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Okay definitely not then.  But this is good info for those who want to start focusing on ES6 development in node.  I will try and update the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Cool, but change the last bit to sed 's/\"//g' -- it's less flakey.

Answer (score 4):

#### node.js

The current version of node.js on ubuntu is 0.10, where 0.12 is stable. You can upgrade via the built-in `n` command as

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

#### MongoDB

MongoDB has updated its repositories to `http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu`. To install

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

(except if you use 12.04, in which case replace `trusty`, but this line works in `vivid`, for example, and you can skip the `keyserver...` step if you had a previous MongoDB-install and just do a `update` and `dist-upgrade`)

References: [Node.js](http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/) and [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)