# How can I install a tar.xz file from nodejs.org?

Tags: software-installation, tar, nodejs

I'm a novice with Ubuntu.

I downloaded `nodejs` from the nodejs.org website.

The file I downloaded is `node-v7.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz`

I know how to extract it, but that's it.

Please explain how I can install it, and where I should put it in the filesystem.

Comment: I recommend you to install Node.js using PPA. Open up your Terminal and run the following commands one-by-one :                                `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`                                                       `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -`                    `sudo apt-get install nodejs`                                                                      It will install latest Node.js active release to your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it if have no choice, because I would prefer to install what I downloaded from the official site, and to know to how to install this type of file

Comment: The most comfortable and reliable way is probably to use a manager like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This little shell script downloads and installs the Node version of your choice. You can also manage multiple versions in parallel and switch between them.

Comment: @GautamVashisht Thanks. I installed the latest 8.X version just replacing `setup_7.x` by `setup_8.x`

Comment: Unzip tar.xz file.
Open extracted directory and go inside bin folder.
Open Terminal over there.
Run following command: sudo mv node /usr/local/bin. 
It should update the node.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to install and switch between multiple versions of node then `nvm` (Node.js version manager) is better option.

1. Check whether you have `nvm` or not.
   If not then you can pull down the nvm installation script from the  [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). The version number may be different, but in general, you can download it with `curl`:

   ```
   curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
   ```

   Run the script with **bash**:

   ```
   bash install_nvm.sh
   ```

   It will install the software into a subdirectory of your home directory at `~/.nvm`. It will also add the necessary lines to your `~/.profile` file to use the file.

   To gain access to the nvm functionality, you'll need to log out and log back in again, or you can source the `~/.profile` file so that your current session knows about the changes:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

---

2. If you have multiple Node.js versions, you can see what is installed by typing:

   ```
   nvm ls
   ```
3. You can install your specific node version by typing:

   ```
   nvm install 6.7.0
   ```
4. If you wish to default one of the versions, you can type:

   ```
   nvm alias default 6.7.0
   ```
5. Now you can also reference it by the alias like this:

   ```
   nvm use default
   ```
6. Check now node version to verify whether changes are made or not by typing:

   ```
   node -v
   ```

Comment: getting some `version GLIBC_2.16 not found (required by node)` error in step-5 `nvm use default`. `nvm ls` clearly says that v15.0.1 is installed. What should I do?

Answer (score 9):

If you only want to install `tar.xz` file from nodejs.org then follow below answer.

Try below links that might help you.

1. [Install NodeJS NPM on Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/10/install-nodejs-npm-linux/)

   if your downloaded `NODE-LTS` file is in `*.tar.xz` format, then replace:

   ```
   tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /usr/save/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```

   with

   ```
   tar --strip-components 1 -xf /usr/save/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
   ```
2. If the above method does not work, then follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330747/what-to-do-with-tar-gz).

---

If these answers do not work, there is another way that works by using `nvm`. This method is specified in another answer.