# npm installed packages are not accessible

Tags: installation, apt, nodejs, npm

I installed nodejs with the instructions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js) on ubuntu 13.1
All went smooth. After that I installed [express](http://expressjs.com/) by issuing the command

```
npm install express
```

which result in

```
express@3.4.4 node_modules/express
├── methods@0.1.0
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
├── fresh@0.2.0
├── debug@0.7.4
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
├── send@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11)
└── connect@2.11.0 (methods@0.0.1, uid2@0.0.3, pause@0.0.1, raw-body@0.0.3, qs@0.6.5, bytes@0.2.1, negotiator@0.3.0, multiparty@2.2.0)
```

but when I now type something like

```
express demo
```

I get

> The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it
>   by typing: sudo apt-get install node-express

Answer (score 2):

I answer my own question for the case that someone else stumble over the same problem.

The packages can be installed as `local` and `global` where `local` is default. We should install the package as `local` when we require it and as `global` when we want to access it within the shell. To install a package as global simply add `-g` in my case I run

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

and now it works.

Edit

Using `-g` and require it later can lead to `UNMET DEPENDENCY express` this can be solved by using `-d`

```
sudo npm install -d express
```