# Issue using Node.js / Express, Says it's not installed

Tags: server, nodejs

I am having the same issue this this person had.

[npm installed packages are not accessible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376950/npm-installed-packages-are-not-accessible)

Where the command "express nodepad" does not work. It give an error that "The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install node-express" However, I did install it using npm with this command "sudo npm install -g express".

When I did ran "sudo npm install -g express" there were no warnings or errors.

What am I missing? Maybe I'm not express correctly?

I was following along with this tutorial.
http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/08/node-tutorial-2/
But where he did "npm install express mongoose jade less expresso" I installed each one separately using a sudo and the -g option.

However, when I get to his command "express nodepad" I get the error. I have also tried to sudo the command and get the message "sudo: express: command not found"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this in terminal: sudo apt-get install node-express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The new version of Express (4.0) does not itself have a bin folder. You have to install express-generator to get the setup functionality.

You are not doing anything wrong. Express has just changed the way it works. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036400/node-js-express-not-working).

Comment: Thank you. I already knew that apt-get install node-express would work by installing an older version, so that is what I had done since my post. I just tested installing the express-generator on a test virtual machine and it worked great. I wonder why hours of google-ing never pointed me to the change? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thanks; node.js evolves fast. I'm glad to now see the 4.2.1 long-term support release is out.