# node js project

Tags: npm

i want to create a project and i have installed nodejs, and i have installed npm and on the terminal when i write "express " it do not make a folder or if it make the "npm start" do not have any response. i have taken reference to http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/
site. 
i have installed C:\node>npm install -g express in thi way...
now when i do this the /usr/bin/npm there is a already created file which is giving error.
Can i delete this file or any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were following a tutorial that was written with Windows in mind, as evidenced by the `C:\node>` prefix in their console.

### To install Node.js on Ubuntu:

There is already a [good question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js/83290#83290) on AskUbuntu about how to install the latest version of Node.js.  I would recommend either [installing using the NVM too](https://askubuntu.com/a/425888/2079), which won't require you to use `sudo` to install packages through `npm`, or [install from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js/83290#83290).

Both of these options will include NPM, so you'll be ready for the next step.

### Generating an app with Express

#### Get the generator

If you want to use Express from the command line to [generate an app](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), you'll need to run `npm install -g express-generator`.  Note that the tool is called `express-generator`, not `express`. And if you installed Node from the PPA, you'll need to add a `sudo` before the `npm install` command.

#### Make a directory

Create a directory for you project:

```
mkdir ~/MyWebApp
```

And change into that directory

```
cd ~/MyWebApp
```

#### Generate

Once inside that directory, you can run the express generator from the command line:

```
express
```

You can also create the directory and generate the app in one step:

```
express MyWebApp
```

Running the above will automatically create a `MyWebApp` folder inside of whatever directory you are currently in, and it will generate the express app there.