# bower install does nothing, not even throw an error

Tags: npm

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. I did `sudo apt-get install npm`. Then I did `npm install -g bower`, which was successful.

With `which npm`, I get `/usr/bin/npm/`.
With `which bower`, I get `/usr/local/bin/bower`.

I cloned a github repository which had a `bower.json`. I try to do `bower install` in the root but nothing happens. As in, it doesn't echo anything, doesn't install anything. It simply does... nothing. I tried `bower --help` and nothing comes up.

I tried `sudo apt-get update` and it says `npm` is up to date. `Nodejs` exists too. Whenever I do anything with npm, it simply does nothing.

EDIT: when I do `npm --global ls`, bower is listed in the directories

What could be the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the content of the `bower.json` file? Could you provide the link to the repository?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It seems to be caused by an incorrect node package.

Removing the *node package* and installing the *legacy package* instead worked for me:

```
apt-get remove node
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: this worked. I built nodejs from source to get it working

Answer (score 22):

This work for me:

```
bower install --force
```

where the `--force` to install forcefully

Comment: Well, it did the trick for me but I wonder why did I have to force it. Thank you.

Comment: You saved my life...

Answer (score 4):

You checked `which npm` and `which bower`, but you didn't check `which node`.  On Ubuntu, the `node` package is unrelated to NodeJS.  The NodeJS package is installed as `nodejs`, which will break any scripts that depend on `node`.  This is similar to another question where [a global installation of jshint wasn't working](https://askubuntu.com/q/519189/2079).

Assuming you have `nodejs` installed, you can create a symlink so that `node` points at `nodejs`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

If that doesn't work, or if you prefer not to use the version of NodeJS in the official repositories, you can [install Node from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/83290/2079) (which will give you both `node` and `nodejs` commands) or [use NVM](https://askubuntu.com/a/531943/2079) (which is my personal preference, as it avoids the need for `sudo` when installing npm modules).

Comment: Well, in addition to creating a symlink, I have to remove the node package too. As mentioned in the other answer that node package is disguising to be an actual nodejs package. So even though after creating a symlink for nodejs, `node` command actually refers to some Amateur Packet Radio Node program, and not the actual nodejs which we desire.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 14.04, I solved it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove node
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there that is having this problem but all the other fixes don't work.  I found that I was typing the wrong command in, I thought it needed a nodejs before the command like:

```
nodejs bower install
```

But bower just executes straight from the terminal

```
bower install
```

Stupid I know!

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Bower package manager can be quickly and easily installed from the Ubuntu Software app. Open Ubuntu Software, search for "bower" and click the *Install* button to install it. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install bower --classic
```

[image]

The bower snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.