# Why npm init is not working - ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, npm

`npm init` is not creating the `package.json` file.

Node version: 0.10.25

I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507855/bower-install-does-nothing-not-even-throw-an-error) on Ask Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove node
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

I would like to know:

- Why this happened?
- How did these commands solve the issue?