# Installing Node.JS through a PPA does not fetch the latest version

Tags: ppa, nodejs

yeah yeah I know, [this has been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js). But when using the `chris-lea` ppa or the "[official way](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)" (which I think is actually the same thing?), after installing you get this:

```
~$ node --version
 v0.10.36
```

So what's the problem? Well the [current version](http://nodejs.org/) of node at the official website is already at **0.12**. that seems like pretty large gap to me.

Is there any ppa that gets updated more frequently?

Comment: btw, I tried adding the [onestone ppa](https://launchpad.net/~onestone/+archive/ubuntu/node.js-0.12) and that installed version 0.11.14 (which is pretty hilarious considering the title for the ppa clearly says **0.12**. That's false advertising if I ever saw it). This is definitely a step in the right direction, but not there yet

Comment: 0.10.36 was released on January 26, 0.11 on January 30 and 0.12 on February 6 (dates from [the blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/)). It's not a big gap in terms of time.

Comment: @muru Wow really? I didn't realize they skipped so quickly. was 0.11 an unstable dev version or something like that?

Comment: 0.11.16 was a stable release (the one on Jan 30). There were a few 0.11.xx development releases before that, but nothing about 0.12.

Comment: @muru so do you think I should stick with the official version and wait for the release?

Comment: That depends on how much of a hurry you're in. I'd give it a couple more weeks. Oh, I made a mistake. 0.11.16 was an unstable release. Don't know why I read Stable. O.o

Comment: @muru no hurry. I just looked at the version differences and thought that maybe this was a poorly updated ppa (like so, so many others)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Installation instructions are here: https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories

> ```
> # Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
>
> # Then install with:
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```

Comment: This is the correct answer, if just wanting NodeJS and not NVM.

Comment: This would install lates nodejs + npm.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to be able to install multiple versions of node then NVM is for you.

To install version NVM and then after install version 0.12 of node:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm install 0.12
```

Then to use:

```
nvm use 0.12
```

**Always check** https://github.com/creationix/nvm for new versions of NVM. When writing this the version was `0.25.0` I doubt it is the same if you read this.

Node Version Manager for the win.

Comment: I am working behind a corp-proxy. This the only solution I found that works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Node.js 0.12 by [ppa:rwky/nodejs](https://answers.launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/ubuntu/nodejs)  PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rwky/nodejs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Ok, but uh, who's `rwky`? Is he an official source? I actually don't like adding random ppa's like that...