# Rails server error: "Could not find a JavaScript runtime."

Tags: command-line, 15.04, ruby-on-rails, terminal-server

trying to run the rails server i get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from /home/acne/Documents/WWW/web/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can i solve this?
Thanks for your time !

Comment: This is the error: `Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)`  Do you have a JS runtime from the list of available runtimes?

Answer (score 2):

Either Install [Node Js](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js) or install [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) gem

```
gem install therubyracer
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Comment the gem "therubyracer".
2. install nodejs.
3. run the server again.