# ./configure not found on new installation of ubuntu

Tags: bash, configure

I am quite unexperienced with ubuntu. As I am now trying to install nodejs via tar.gz package I dont get the `./configure` to work.

As you may read anywhere, an installation consists basicly of these steps:
1. Download tar.gz package
2. Extract
3. Open Terminal
4. cd into the source folder
5. $ ./configure
6. $ make
7. $ sudo make install
8. -- Install completed --

No matter if I perform Step 5. with root root or not, I'm getting this Error:
`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

It may surely not be a configuration error, because I've just reinstalled the OS about 2 hours ago.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT:
I've downloaded the Linux-Binarys of Nodejs [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). But as I think about it now, I should be using the sourcecode packege. Shouldn't I?

Comment: `./configure` isn't a thing that's *"on"* Ubuntu: it's a script that *may* be provided by the package: what exactly did you download, and from where? [Edit] your question to include a link if possible. What directory are you in exactly when you try to execute the command?

Comment: @steeldriver added link. So there should be a directory `configure` inside the package to get it to work? seems simple. - But in this case, I dont get why the usage of `./configure` is even suggested in the readme-file.

Comment: If you've downloaded one of the *binary* packages, then you don't need to configure or make anything - that's only required for the *source code* .tar.gz package

Comment: @steeldriver so how is it installed then? do I need to copy it anywhere?

Comment: I don't have experience with nodejs: however I suggest you refer to [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js?) and [How to Install Node.js on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/#maintained-ubuntu-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your Ideas.

I managed to install it with [this](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/#standard-binary-packages) tutorial.

**1. Get Processor architecture**

```
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
```

**2. Download package** *using correct version and CPU Architecture*

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.4/node-v4.2.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

**3. Unpack to `/usr/local**  *using correct version and CPU Architecture*

```
 sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v4.2.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

**Works**

> I also tried *Install Node.js with Maintained Ubuntu Packages* from the same link which didn't work, due to failures inside the bash-script.

Comment: You may set your own answer as the accepted. 3 years, now  you may already got experience with Unix like systems. As general info, always look for `INSTALL`,  `README` files or any doc/help folder, most developers document such imported instructions (HOWTO install).