# How to build Nodejs for an arm64 architecture machine?

Tags: compiling, nodejs

I'm trying to build Nodejs from source for my Netgear ReadyNAS (Powered by an arm64 architecture).
I'd plan to follow the step described in [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js) but I could not do the step `./configure`.

Here are the only files I have in the .tar.gz:

```
admin@ReadyNAS:/usr/local/src/node-v7.2.1-linux-arm64$ ls -a
.  ..  bin  CHANGELOG.md  include  lib  LICENSE  README.md  share
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why couldnt you do that step? Any error prompted? What exactly happened?

Comment: I've got a error message : admin@ReadyNAS:/usr/local/src/node-v6.9.1-linux-arm64$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: See (and maybe vote+choose) Atul Agrawal's answer below. You seem to have downloaded the binary archive, not the source one. But is it really necessary that you recompile the sources? Cross-compilation is not easy. Aren't the binaries enough?

Comment: Yes, you're are right, I have downloaded binaries instead of sources ... I'm trying to build Node.js because I encountered error if I'm using binaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded the binaries.

Please use this link
https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

and click on source code link where you will find the actual source code.

Comment: The page reads "Latest Current Version: v7.2.1" which seems to be the version Babnonet13 downloaded. What makes you think this is a download error? The OP only mentions a `./configure` error.

Comment: bascically i meant is that the download from home page will not give the whole source code

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it. You may well be right. Can you please add this to your answer?

Comment: Yes it seems the source code is not complete ... (file for the configuration step are missing) ... but where can I download the complete source code ?

Comment: Please download that from above link