# sudo: node : command not found

Tags: command-line, sudo, nodejs

I have a problem related to nodejs. I have nodejs binaries here: `~/node-v8.5.0-linux-x64/` and I have a soft link that I created using: `ln -s node-v8.5.0-linux-x64/ node`.

In my .bashrc, I have this: `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/node/bin`.

`node` and `npm` are working great when I'm normally logged in. As both of them are installed in my home, I don't need to be logged in as root to install a package globally.

But I wanted to try; so, I ran:

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
sudo node app.js
```

and it didn't work.

```
sudo: node : command not found
```

I thought maybe the `$PATH` changes when I use `sudo` but then I checked it using `sudo echo $PATH`:

```
/home/dc/bin:/home/dc/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dc/node/bin
```

The shell should know where to go when I type `node` command, but it seems it doesn't. I also tried `-H`, `-i` and `-u` options for `sudo` but none of that helps either.

Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: I think something installation or symbolic link  issue, follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js/866436#866436

Comment: @Nullpointer Nope. He has `node`/`npm` installed in his home directory, which is only part of his own user's `$PATH`. And the assumption that `sudo` preserves the `$PATH` variable is wrong, as detailed in my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, `sudo` does **not** preserve your `$PATH` environment variable for security reasons. Instead, it gets replaced with a `secure_path` defined in `/etc/sudoers`, which you should not change.

```
$ sudo grep secure_path /etc/sudoers
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

You think to have verified that the `$PATH` variable stays the same with your command

```
sudo echo $PATH
```

but actually Bash expands variables before starting to execute any (here the `sudo`) command, which means the line above shows your own `$PATH` value. To get the one as `sudo`, use e.g.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

What you can do is to e.g. resolve the command you want to run (`node` or `npm`) in your own user's shell using process substitution with `which`:

```
sudo "$(which npm)" install -g angular-cli
sudo "$(which node)" app.js
```

This first runs `which npm` or `which node` as your user, which returns the absolute path of the executables belonging to the specified commands. Then that output is literally inserted into your `sudo` command, so `sudo` actually believes it got executed with absolute paths like below, removing the need to look anything up in `$PATH`:

```
sudo /home/dc/node/bin/npm install -g angular-cli
sudo /home/dc/node/bin/node app.js
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just create a soft link for node, npm and npx in the /sbin directory
e.g.

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.14.1-linux-x64/bin/node /sbin/node
```

Syntax > `ln -s (source) (destination)`

Now running `sudo node` should work