# install node latest version in linux

Tags: apt, nodejs, wget

i am new in linux and want install node with bellow command:

`sudo apt-get install curl`

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

and angular 8 needs `node 12.x`

i remove node with `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs` and run bellow command but it installed perverse version

`sudo apt-get install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: Which version of Linux are you using? Which release number? Please help us help you by providing that information. Please put that into your question by clicking [edit]. Don't use Ask Comment; instead, click [edit].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

1. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`
2. `sudo apt install nodejs`
3. Check: `$ node --version`
   Output: v10.16.3
4. Check: `$ npm --version`
   Output: 6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using [n](https://github.com/tj/n). After installing node in any way, eg. [as described below](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

you should have `npm` available. Install `n` with:

`npm install -g n`

and select correct version

- `n lsr` to list available versions
- `n latest` to use latest
- `n 12.0.0` to use 12.0

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command

> sudo n lts

if you want to  install update version then run command

> sudo install  n16.15.1

This work for me fine.