# How to install Node.js v12.x:

Tags: nodejs

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.3 LTS. I am trying to install Node.js v12. but i can see that Version: 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4 can only be installed in my ubuntu . How to upgrade the version of node from 8.10.0 to 12?I tried many solutions but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js) —. [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js/1240153#1240153)

Comment: @karel - solution mentioned by you didn't work

Comment: Node.js 12 is the default snap package version in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. For more information run `snap info node`

Comment: so i ran the "sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable" and triedto check the version of node . Error pops out "bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory" . So where would the nodeget install? as it says "snap node is alreadyinstalled"?

Comment: `snap run node` will print the node.js version and show the node command line prompt which is a single `>` character.

Comment: yes. it worked. thanks for the help.

Comment: If this duplicate link answered your question please click in the blue banner above your question to confirm that the duplicate link worked,