# Why I don't have the latest node version?

Tags: 20.04, nodejs, 21.04

I installed node with the command `sudo apt install nodejs`, and then I check the version with the command `node --version` and i Get that I have **v12.21.0** node version. But on nodeJS website I see that the latest version is  **14.17.3**.
Why is that?
And what can I do to get the latest version of node?
I must use the latest version because this version do not get the new syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: you can install the latest version of nodejs from the nodeSource. Here is the installation instruction for every version https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions and it is listed as officail nodejs package manger https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things to add repositories to my system and stuff like that, but nothing worked for me. One thing I did find, is that you can download binaries from https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/, although that's probably not recommendable. I haven't been able to install one of the binaries due to dependency issues other issues, so try at your own risk.

Update: I have been able to install a `18.7.0` binary ([this one](https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_18.7.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb))

Update 2: You can install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and run `nvm install <version` and `nvm use <version>`