# Update NodeJS from 10.19.0 to 14.17.3 LTS in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lts, nodejs, npm

I am using Ionic and my builds are failing. It says I need to have the latest npm and node.js. Sadly, my attempts so far from another [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js) and `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` etc is failing to move the version of t `14.17.3 LTS` which the website says is the `latest LTS`.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

I have many setups and do not want to break others too. It would be very kind if someone can provide the right commands to update to the `latest npm and nodejs LTS`.

The topics I went through has commands to specific versions and are old. Thanks.

Update 1 :

I installed nodejs 14 from Snap store. But no idea where it is now. When I use nodejs --version it shows v10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
With this tool you can utilize any version of node, side by side on the same machine.

You can install it with `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

Then download your desired node version `nvm install 14` .

Nvm has many other options for managing your node runtimes so check the man page.

Comment: Ionic asks for npm. If I use nvm, will there be any problem ? Thanks

Comment: I tried these but it ways `Now using node v14.17.3 (npm v6.14.13)
Creating default alias: default -> 14 (-> v14.17.3)
user@username:~$ nodejs --version
v10.19.0`

Comment: It is working for me even though it shows v10. Thanks.

Comment: You can check node version with `node -v`

Comment: Don't forget to use `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using installation instructions from official Node.js website - [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/). Namely for Ubuntu you'll be directed to [nodesource/distributions at GitHub](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md). Find the following paragraph - [Installation instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions). It stated for example:

```
Node.js v14.x:

# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks, even after trying the command as root, it says `nodejs is already the newest version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1).`

Comment: That just means it's the latest version of nodejs that is available in your ubuntu repo. To update beyond what is included with your version of ubuntu (20.04?), you need to use the above method offered by @Serg