# what's the canonical way to install nodejs on an Ubuntu desktop (21.x)?

Tags: nodejs

I understand that apt is NOT the regular way

I see 3 options:

1. download and run an opaque script from the nodejs sites
2. umake (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)
3. asdf (https://asdf-vm.com/)

I'd like to take a look at the Tryton web client (named Sao) and nodejs is a requirement

How am I supposed to get that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js) (`sudo snap install node --classic --channel version/stable` where you replace `version` with a 1-digit or 2-digit version number)

Comment: @karel Amazingly, this answer is still valid after 10 years.

Comment: did snap exist 10 years ago ? Wow

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference, but generally I'd use the Node Version Manager [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) because it facilitates side-by-side installations (and easy de-installations) of major Node versions.