# sudo apt install: Always installs old packages

Tags: apt, sudo

I wanted to run the `yarn install` command but then it told me that my nodejs was outdated. I checked the website to see what the latest version was and its 16.14.2 LTS. However, when I run `node --version` it shows `v10.19.0`.

I decided to check my python version too and it showed `Python 2.7.18`.

I tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` `sudo apt upgrade package_name` and tried to reinstall those packages to no avail

EDIT: Im sorry for not stating my question. Im not asking why, Im asking how I can install the latest version of these packages rather than the old versions that the APT tool has. Is it even possible?

EDIT 2: Or is there some tutorial I can follow for just downloading these packages from their official websites? Because I struggle with that. The only packages I've managed to install directly are Discord and Brave which had AppImages.

EDIT 3: Im on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 LTS. Also, would switching to Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 resolve this?

Comment: What Ubuntu release do you have? `lsb_release -a` There must be an old release, possibly unsupported, so it might be a good time to "upgrade".

Comment: @mikewhatever Im on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the latest version of node.js?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49390/) The latest version of the python interpreter in Ubuntu is invoked by running `python3` , not `python`